# Install module from sibling directory

Tags: python

I would like to have a following structure in a project:

```
/
    lib/
        common/
            __init__.py
            common.py
        setup.py
    alpha/
        main.py
        Dockerfile
    beta/
        main.py
        Dockerfile
    Jenkinsfile
```

In the build process I want to build a module `common` and then use that as a dependency of `alpha` and `beta`.

I don't want to have `common` as a separate project/repo. In fact, this is my current state and I'm using `pip install git+https://<repo>` - but I decided I prefer components to share lifecycle, so to keep them together. And I think pip install from Git is not too the cleanest approach either.

The simplest thing might be to copy entire lib into alpha/beta and just use the source. Not being expert in Python I can't say how "nice" this would be, but anyway running `docker build` from within subdirectory doesn't give me access to any context outside of that subdirectory.

Can you suggest an efficient and clean approach?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building the module locally:

```
# in ./lib
python3 -m build --wheel
```

And then pulling it into images with:

```
# in all of ./alpha, ./beta and others
cp ../lib/dist/common-$version-py3-none-any.whl ./wheel/
```

Finally, in Dockerfiles:

```
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./wheel ./wheel
RUN python3 -m pip install ./wheel/common-$version-py3-none-any.whl
```